# What is this houseplant with white-speckled red and green leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

[image]

I have a houseplant that was given to me. It was mostly dead when I first got it but it has a tree-like branch that the foliage grows from with red and green leaves, red underneath, and white speckles on the top of them. It looked like a stick with nothing on it when I got it, now it has 9 big red and green leaves on it. I have no clue what kind of plant this is. I've been caring for it for months and I would really like to know!

I was told it was a bonsai but I don't have much knowledge of bonsais.

Answer (score 8):

The asymmetrical leaves, the pattern and the slightly "wing" shape clearly indicate a **[begonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begonia)** (not a [bonsai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonsai)!). This is a rather large group of plants, some cultivars bred for their flowers, others for their variegated leaves.

Your specimen *could* be a begonia corallina hybrid, but a small one. Identification of begonias is often difficult because an almost innumerable amount of hybrids exist. By your pictures I can at least say that it's a cane-type begonia. You may find the website of the [American Begonia Society](http://www.begonias.org/greenhouse/cane.htm) on cane begonias helpful for further research.

Answer (score 4):

it is an Angel wing begonia that has pink heart shaped cluster flowers --

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is an angel wing begonia. I got a start ( one stem with three leaves ) from a friend who was 102 years old.  And seven years later,  I have three pots full! Some of mine are three feet tall, and they get beautiful little clumps of heart shaped flowers. This is a strong plant that will last for years. I hope yours grows as well as mine has!